# Django: how to get multiple input?

Tags: python, django

I m working on cylinder management system in which i want to give functionality that user can issue multiple cylinder.
What i m wanting that user get a list of available cylinder where he can choose the cylinders item and submit the form.

I m able to handle this for single cylinder , here is what i m applying for single cylinder:-

models:-

```
class Cylinder(models.Model):
    stachoice=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty') 
    ]
    substachoice=[
    ('Available','available'), 
    ('Unavailable','unavailable'),
    ('Issued','issued') 
    
    ]
    cylinderId=models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True,null=False)
    gasName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cylinderSize=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=stachoice,default='fill')
    Availability=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=substachoice,default="Available")
    EntryDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    issue_Date=models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    issue_user=models.CharField(max_length=70,null=True)
    return_Date=models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cylinderDetail',args=[(self.cylinderId)])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cylinderId)

class Issue(models.Model):
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('Cylinder',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=60,null=False)
    issueDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk: 
            if self.cylinder.Availability=='Available':
                Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability=('Issued'))
                Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(issue_Date=self.issueDate)
                Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(issue_user=self.userName)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
        
    def __str__(self):
        
        return str(self.userName) 


class Return(models.Model):
    fill=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty'),
    ('refill','Refill')
    ]

    ava=[
    ('yes','YES'),
    ('no','NO')
    ]
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('Cylinder',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    availability=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=ava)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=fill)
    returnDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:

            if self.cylinder.Availability=='Issued':
                Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(return_Date=self.returnDate)
                if self.availability=='YES' or self.availability=='yes':
                    Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability='Available')
                    if self.status=='empty' or self.status=='Empty':
                        Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Empty')
                else:
                    Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability='Unavailable')
                    if self.status=='refill' or self.status=='Refill':
                        Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Refill')
                    if self.status=='empty' or self.status=='Empty':
                        Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Empty')


        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cylinder)
```

views:-

```
@login_required
def issue(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return redirect('index')
    
    form=IssueForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=IssueForm(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(cylinderListView)
            
    return render(request,'entry/cylinder_form.html',{'form':form})
```

form template:-

```
<div class='col-lg-12' id="divForm">
  
  <br>
  
    <div class="form-group " id="form1">
        <h3>New Entry</h3>
        <form method="post"  >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input class="btn btn-success " type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

I m not able to write code for multiple cylinder issue.

Comment: Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability=('Issued'))

Why are you doing this for multiple issue just store the data in the issue model. If you are not doing so then what is the use of Issue model or I am not understanding your question.

Comment: Check out formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: @sumitsubedi It was when i m doing for single cylinder and i just want do change the availability in cylinder table  when a cylinder is issued , i will be very thank ful if you suggest any other good way to do this

Comment: so you are telling even once a cylinder is issued then you want to change the availability on the cylinder table but the cylinder can be issued by multiple user.

Comment: sorry,I didn't get you . I just want that in issue form user get multiple input for cylinder id , so in one form submit  he/she can able to issue multiple cylinder Id to one single user . and when it issue all cylinder it will update Availability Status of all selected cylinder Id to be Issued.